# MaxConnections and App.config question

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have a multipart downloader, and to get it working I'm using this app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup>
<system.net>
<connectionManagement>
    <add address="*" maxconnection="65000" />
</connectionManagement>
</system.net>
</configuration>
```

How can I put that file into my executable or somehow set this param internally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 65000;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx

Comment: Are equivalent the 2 methods ?